# Google BigQuery Error: Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: google-bigquery

I get a "resources exceeded" error when I run the following simple query in BigQuery, most of the answers to this error refer to the EACH clause , but I am not using any such clause in my query.

```
SELECT
  XXX_lnaourj_ID,
  XXX_DR_Tma_LC,
  XXX_CR_Tma_LC,
  XXX_Amount_LC,
  XXX_TLAffect_LC,
  XXX_Entry_Desc,
  XXX_DocType,
  XXX_TCode,
  XXX_Company,
  XXX_Posted_By,
  XXX_Parked_By,
  XXX_Accounting_Date,
  XXX_Creation_Date
FROM
  [acl_data.XXX_JE_All_Formatted]
WHERE
  XXX_lnaourj_ID IN (
  SELECT
    XXX_lnaourj_ID
  FROM
    [acl_data.XXX_JE_All_Formatted]
  WHERE
    XXX_Creation_Date - XXX_Accounting_Date > 30 )
ORDER BY
  XXX_lnaourj_ID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove ORDER BY and it should work

I think BigQuery engine translates your query using JOIN (and that's why you see it is referenced), so another option for you would be to rewrite your query using JOIN explicitly and try it with and/or without EACH clause

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191584/5221944 for more details from bigquery teammember

> Edit

I haven't realized it is the same table! Why not to use something like below?

```
SELECT
  XXX_lnaourj_ID,
  XXX_DR_Tma_LC,
  XXX_CR_Tma_LC,
  XXX_Amount_LC,
  XXX_TLAffect_LC,
  XXX_Entry_Desc,
  XXX_DocType,
  XXX_TCode,
  XXX_Company,
  XXX_Posted_By,
  XXX_Parked_By,
  XXX_Accounting_Date,
  XXX_Creation_Date
FROM [acl_data.XXX_JE_All_Formatted]
WHERE XXX_Creation_Date - XXX_Accounting_Date > 30
```

Comment: But what if I want to sort it ? The link you gave me does not address the query at hand. Thanks.

Comment: extra link is just for some extra reading :o)  - i actually gave you answer with few options - do they worked for you?

Comment: I rewrote it using join on the same table but then  I get the same error even if do not use the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: in this case - i recommend you to update your question with this info + re-written query - so you will have chance for better answer or/and i follow up on my answer

Comment: Because the same XXX_lnaourj_ID could be present in both the cases i.e. where XXX_Creation_Date - XXX_Accounting_Date > 30 and XXX_Creation_Date - XXX_Accounting_Date < 30 , however if the difference is > 30 then I need all the rows for the XXX_lnaourj_ID . Hope I am clear. Thank you.

Comment: agree. that's exactly what is in my comment to your twin question

Comment: SELECT
  JE_All1.xxx_Journal_ID,
  JE_All1.xxx_DR_Amt_LC,
  JE_All1.xxx_CR_Amt_LC,
  JE_All1.xxx_Amount_LC,
  JE_All1.xxx_PLImpact_LC,
  JE_All1.xxx_Entry_Desc,
  JE_All1.xxx_DocType,
  JE_All1.xxx_TCode,
  JE_All1.xxx_Company,
  JE_All1.xxx_Posted_By,
  JE_All1.xxx_Parked_By,
  JE_All1.xxx_Accounting_Date,
  JE_All1.xxx_Creation_Date
FROM
  [acl_data.xxx_JE_All_Formatted] as JE_All1
JOIN
  [acl_data.xxx_JE_All_Formatted] as JE_All2 
  ON JE_All1.xxx_Journal_ID = JE_All2.xxx_Journal_ID
  WHERE
  JE_All2.xxx_Creation_Date - JE_All2.xxx_Accounting_Date > 30 
  order by JE_All1.xxx_Journal_ID ASC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107887/discussion-between-user1965449-and-mikhail-berlyant).